# How do I turn 360 degrees in Portal on Steam/Linux?

Tags: steam, portal

Ubuntu 20.04LTS fully updated. Installed the `steam` package. Have used Steam on Linux on a previous install. When I run Portal, keyboard controls and both mouse buttons work correctly. However, I can only turn my body 90 degrees when sliding the mouse left or right. Occasionally, I can get the 90 degree range to shift (e.g. by looking straight down and moving left or right with `A` or `D`), but after doing that, I'm stuck to a new 90 degree viewing range. This makes even simple tasks frustratingly difficult. Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds? Seems to be specific to Steam/Portal as I have no mouse issues outside of Steam.

Comment: I tried Portal 2 in Steam (on Ubuntu 20.04LTS) and don't have this problem.

Comment: That is an extremely weird behaviour, do youhave other screens and your mouse isn't locked to the game, perhaps? I can't imagine what would cause this

Comment: One (vertically oriented) screen. Not sure how I'd check whether the mouse is locked to the game, but I don't have any special mouse config. Is there somewhere I can look to check on locking? Thanks for reading!

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue at all if you are only using a single screen. Sorry I can't help

Comment: Yup, I'm just using one screen. Definitely a weird one!